# ubuntu-device-flash snap not found

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I'm trying to build a custom Ubuntu Core image for my Raspberry Pi 3 (with preinstalled snaps) and I know that this is not yet supported.

I thought I could try the ubuntu-device-flash tool anyways (I found [this](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/porting/) and [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PublicationNotes#Generating_raspberry_pi2_images_.2816.29), and the pi3 oem snap).

The second page suggests installing ubuntu-device-flash as a snap, using

`$ sudo snap install --channel=edge --devmode ubuntu-device-flash`

but on my Ubuntu 16.04 server this gives me

`error: cannot install "ubuntu-device-flash": snap not found`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that you found some now outdated reference: `ubuntu-device-flash` is deprecated in favor of `ubuntu-image`.
You can find its code on launchpad: https://code.launchpad.net/~mvo/ubuntu-image/+git/ubuntu-image/+ref/master (there is as well a package for yakkety).

No official documentation is available yet (it's a question of days, I'm told and will be published on http://snapcraft.io). Meanwhile, you can play with it and use --help to check the syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I also saw this [thread](https://lists.snapcraft.io/archives/devices/2016-September/000005.html) which gives some explanation, but I couldn't find a pi3 model assertion -- I'll just wait for the release then